# Serve static files in Express JS. Getting an error when loading type="module" js file

Tags: vue.js, express, ngrok

I have an Express JS server, and have included a Vue.js 3 application in a separate folder.

After I've built the VueJS app, I'm trying to statically serve it. This works fine locally. However, when I was testing the static side on Render or on Ngrok, I can't view the UI, it fails to load the `type="module"` JS file and I get a 400 response.

It's odd since it works fine locally, and when I host it over Render / Ngrok, the CSS file seems to load fine, but just the JS file which causes the error

The Express is as follows:

```js
// Using node-version 18
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const vueStaticMiddleware = express.static(path.join(dirname, 'client/dist'));

app.use(vueStaticMiddleware);
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on PORT: ${PORT}`));
```

The folder structure is:

```js
- client (Vue) /
  - dist/
    - assets/
      - index-65bbd409.js
      - index-159be68d.css
    - index.html
- index.js (Express)
```

The client/dist/index/html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Vue App</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-65bbd409.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-159be68d.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

The error

[Module JS not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTxHg.png)

[Console / Network Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ApFv.png)

I've tried changing the static end point and various other things, however, to no avail

Any ideas / thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: The 400 response is very odd. What do you get if you try and open the `.js` file directly in your browser

Comment: @Phil Yeah very odd indeed. I'm able to open the JS file in the browser. From 'Insepect Element' I'm able to right-click on the js file and it opens fine in another tab! So it's not an issue of incorrect directory or anything

Comment: Could the `crossorigin` attribute on the `<script>` tag be causing a problem?  What happens if you remove that?

Comment: When you open the file directly, is it still served with a 400 status? You can use the dev-tools _Network_ panel to see, just reload the URL with it open

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah I thought the same earlier, I tried to remove it, however, it made no difference unfortunately 

Comment: @Phil when I open the file directly, I get a 304 status https://imgur.com/a/IlejgEd

Comment: Do a hard refresh please (Ctrl+Shift+R / Command+Shift+R)

Comment: @Phil ah yeah sorry, so on a hard refresh, I get a 200 status. It doesn't make sense. The file is loaded in fine, its just because when you add `type="module"` it starts having issues

Comment: The `type` really shouldn't make a difference to the HTTP request / response. If you do a hard refresh on your index page, does it still get the 400 status for the `.js` file?

Comment: I literally just found the answer, it was CORs related. Since I was using Ngrok the URL wasn't in the whitelist. Its just there was no CORs error presented, so I didn't think of it earlier. 

Thanks for all your efforts @Phil! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that if I'm using ngrok or Render to host it, the URL wasn't whitelisted in my CORs config. After whitelisting it, it resolved the issue!

It was hard to find the cause since there was no CORS error presented